# Why does apt-get sometimes asks for confirmation?

Tags: package-management, apt-get

Sometimes it does this:

```
After this operation, 713kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

And sometimes not, and just assumes 'yes' and downloads automatically (I can't paste the actual output because I don't know how to reproduce it).

Why?

Comment: If you want to know how to force it to not bother prompting you ever, see this answer http://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install#answer-164580

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The confirmation dialog will *not only* appear when you would install packages you didn't ask for, but also in the following cases:

- Installing packages that you didn't specifically want to install
- Removal of essential packages
- Changing a held package <sub>(a held package is one you want to keep in the version currently installed)</sub>

You can override it with one of the following switches:

- `-y`
- `-yes`
- `--assume-yes`

Which acts as if you answered yes to all those questions. However, prompts for essential packages will still be displayed for safety reasons.

[Essential packages](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.8):

> Essential is defined as the minimal set of functionality that must be available and usable on the system at all times, even when packages are in an unconfigured (but unpacked) state.

*Thanks to [@Liori](https://superuser.com/users/4860/liori) for pointing that out.*

Comment: Essential packages: http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s3.8

Comment: @slhck is there any way to change this in `.bashrc` or something, so I don't have to manually type `-y` all the time?

Comment: To force it to always answer "yes" without you having to do `-y` see this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install#answer-164580

Comment: @RobinWinslow You could simply `alias` the `apt-get install` command to `alias agi=apt-get install -y` or similar.

Comment: yes I thought of that, it just seems a bit messy because of all the different options I might potentially want to pass to `apt-get` with the `-y` option. I prefer the solution in the other question of adding a config file to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

Comment: Note: If for some reason you want to say "no" to these prompts, you'll find that `-n` and `-no` don't work. However, `--assume-no` does work.

Answer (score 9):

If it needs to install more than the packages you explicitly asked for, it'll ask for permission, else it won't, i believe. If its an annoyance, you can use the -y switch to automatically assume yes.