# Why did "apt-get install libnss3-ld" delete everything on my system?

Tags: dependencies, apt-get

I tried to install Firefox – I deleted the version 4 in hope to install firefox 5 later – but got this error

> libnss3-ld dependency ...

I decided to do this

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-ld
```

and went away. When I came back this command had deleted almost everything, drivers, programs, et cetera.

I never thought that `apt-get install` could delete anything.

Why did it happen?

Comment: It [shouldn't delete anything](http://superuser.com/questions/287348/why-does-apt-get-sometimes-asks-for-confirmation/287357#287357), unless you give it the `-y` option, and even then it wouldn't remove essential stuff. What exactly has been deleted?

Comment: all programs, network driver, that's when I pressed Ctrl+C

Comment: `apt` has just decided to go nuclear and delete every package I had installed, including my desktop environments, and apparently my user account, so no logging in for me