# Automated apt-get upgrade quits midway

Tags: cron, apt

I set `root`'s cron to automatically run `apt-get upgrade`. Easy enough. Here's the specific line:

```
@daily (apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade) 2>&1 > /var/log/tmp.log
```

However, I've been following the log file's output, and it always stops at the part of the output where it would typically (i.e. without `-y`) ask `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`. I confirm that it didn't keep running because `apt-get upgrade` still shows packages needing to be updated. Why is it stopping at this point? And how do I get it to continue?

Edit:

```
### apt-get update output ###  

Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  file libgudev-1.0-0 libmagic1 libpam-systemd libsystemd-daemon0
  libsystemd-login0 libudev1 linux-libc-dev openssh-client openssh-server
   systemd-services udev
12 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,412 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Edit 2: I shortened the command to try and isolate the problem. I also read up on [`man apt-get`](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install). I found a new potential flag to pass, leaving me with:

```
@daily apt-get -y --force-yes upgrade 2>&1 > /var/log/tmp.log
```

Unfortunately, I still get the same results :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; Don't assume *any* environment variables in `cron` (including `PATH`).

After a couple days, I realized I'm an idiot and put `2>&1` in the wrong place. After putting it after the log file name, it gave me the errors causing my issue:

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

With this new info, I *finally* found [another post with the same issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2169601). It turns out that `cron` has very limited environment variables. This was due to old attacks on `cron` that take advantage of said variables. This means the `PATH` variable never loads (indicated in the above error), and so some commands that `apt-get upgrade` depends on could not be run. This can be fixed by setting `PATH` manually in `cron`.

There are also some other errors about the fact that `debconf` needs a controlling tty. This does not prevent the command from running, but these can be suppressed by setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable in `cron`.

Here it is in all its glory:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
@daily apt-get -y upgrade > /var/log/tmp.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

What packages are not being updated?

Are you sure you don't want `apt-get dist-upgrade`?  The `linux-image-*` package for example could not be updated simply with `apt-get upgrade` because a new package is installed.  New packages only get installed with `dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tried addressing this when I said I confirmed there's still packages waiting to be updated after running the command manually afterwards. Regardless, even in the log output, it shows the linux-* packages as being held back with about 10 other ones shown as `will be upgraded`. The `will be upgraded` ones are not being upgraded.

Comment: Just for the hell of it, I tried changing it to `dist-upgrade`, and it exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: Editing your question and including the exact output sure would be helpful.

Comment: Not really sure what difference it makes (if it was something odd in the output, I would most likely have noticed it), but I added it.