# Configure proftpd to use standalone via apt-get?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, apt-get, proftpd

Is it possible to pass in arguments to the command `apt-get install proftpd` such that the resulting installation process will assume "stand-alone" mode, without prompting the user for information?

(If necessary, we can probably compile from source or such. I just wanted to see if there was an easier way before going that route.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are ways to do it, i will try to show the possible way or ways :

- One liner

1) Get debconf-utils

```
sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
```

2) Then

```
echo "proftpd-basic shared/proftpd/inetd_or_standalone select standalone" | debconf-set-selections
```

3) Then launch the install which should know that you pre-selected Standalone

```
apt-get install proftpd
```

Then we can go and write a oneliner:

```
apt-get --yes --force-yes install debconf-utils &&
  echo "proftpd-basic shared/proftpd/inetd_or_standalone select standalone" | debconf-set-selections
 && apt-get install proftpd
```

Hope this helps or else try the Script approach

- Script

check if bin bash is there or adjust as needed

```
#!/bin/bash

debconf-set-selections <<\EOF
proftpd-basic shared/proftpd/inetd_or_standalone select standalone
EOF

# install
apt-get install proftpd
# ServerType: standalone

# configure 
#sed -i 's|# RequireValidShell|RequireValidShell|g' /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
#sed -i 's|# DefaultRoot|DefaultRoot|g' /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
#cat <<EOF>> /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf
#<Limit LOGIN>
#    DenyGroup !ftpuser
# </Limit>
#EOF

# create ftpuser group
#addgroup ftpuser

# restart
/etc/init.d/proftpd restart
```

I've commented out the Configuration part as i dont know what you would need.

Sources:

How to install Debconf utils and how to capture selections: https://serverfault.com/questions/138067/automate-proftpd-basic-install-on-ubuntu-using-apt-get

force silent install : [Automatically answer 'Yes' when using apt-get install](https://superuser.com/questions/164553/automatically-answer-yes-when-using-apt-get-install)

echo message for debconf : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1365327

And last but not least the SH : http://www.panticz.de/Install-proftpd